# How does umbraco.cms.businesslogic.template.Template.Import work?

Tags: umbraco

Does anyone happen to know how

`umbraco.cms.businesslogic.template.Template Import(System.Xml.XmlNode n, umbraco.BusinessLogic.User u)`

in the Umbraco API works? More specifically what the XMLNode you're supposed to pass in looks like (is supposed to be)? I've been searching for a reference on this method for a while now, can't seem to find anything. The API reference on the Umbraco wiki isn't helping much either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, here is the source code for the function:

```
public static Template Import(XmlNode n, User u)
{
    string alias = xmlHelper.GetNodeValue(n.SelectSingleNode("Alias"));

    Template t = Template.GetByAlias(alias);

    if (t == null)
    {
        t = MakeNew(xmlHelper.GetNodeValue(n.SelectSingleNode("Name")), u);
    }

    t.Alias = alias;

    t.ImportDesign(xmlHelper.GetNodeValue(n.SelectSingleNode("Design")));

    return t;
 }
```